# MVVM, WPF Ribbon V4, with Prism

Tags: c#, wpf

This weekend I've been having one heck of a time getting WPF Ribbon v4 working with MVVM and Prism (using unity). After much trial and error, I believe I have it working. I was hoping someone could take a look at it and give me some feedback.

RibbonRegionAdapter.cs

```
public class RibbonRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<Ribbon>
{
    private Ribbon _ribbonTarget;

    public RibbonRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviorFactory)
        : base(regionBehaviorFactory)
    {

    }

    protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, Ribbon regionTarget)
    {
        _ribbonTarget = regionTarget;

        region.Views.CollectionChanged += delegate {  
            foreach (RibbonTab tab in region.Views.Cast<RibbonTab>())  
            {  
                if (!_ribbonTarget.Items.Contains(tab))  
                {  
                    _ribbonTarget.Items.Add(tab);  
                }  
            }  
        };  
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new SingleActiveRegion();
    }
}
```

BootStrapper.cs - To register our regionAdapter

```
    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();

        if (mappings != null)
        {
            mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(Ribbon), this.Container.Resolve<RibbonRegionAdapter>());
        }


        return mappings;
    }
```

CarRibbonTab.xaml

```
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Class="CarManager.Modules.CarModule.Views.CarRibbonTab"
               xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Header="Officers">
    <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="New">

    </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
    <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Manage">
        <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="Make"
                                LargeImageSource="..\Resources\make.png" />
        <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="Inventory"
                                LargeImageSource="..\Resources\Inventory.png" />
        <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="Assignments" />
    </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
```

CarRibbonTab.cs - Code behind for the View

```
public partial class CarRibbonTab: RibbonTab
{
    public CarRibbonTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Shell.xaml - Just showing the ribbon control

```
<ribbon:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top" Title="CarManager" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RibbonRegion">
    <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\Icon.png">
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Exit"
                                              ImageSource="Images\ExitIcon.png"/>
        </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
    </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

CarModule.cs - registering the view with the region

```
    public class CarModule: IModule
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager  _regionManager;
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
        public MenuItemViewModel MenuItem;

        public CarModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _container     = container;
            _regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            //Ribbon
            _container.RegisterType<Object, CarRibbonTab>("CarRibbonTab");

            _regionManager.AddToRegion("RibbonRegion", _container.Resolve<CarRibbonTab>());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Scott, could you please tell in which problem scenario you have used RibbonRegionAdapter, or Why we need to have one when developing Apps using Ribbon control with prism ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure whether we have many Prism specialists on Code Review and I haven't worked with it for a while, so maybe my comments are incorrect at points.

1. I do not really like the way you're handling `region.Views.CollectionChanged` event. This event provides a lot of information in eventArgs but you're ignoring it. Firstly you do not handle removing views at all. Secondly instead of iterating through all views every time I would use those from `eventArgs` (`NewItems` property).
2. I believe generally it is better to have views isolated from regions in terms of concrete types. Your view is not isolated since it has to inherit `RibbonTab` class. Maybe it is not an issue here and I'm not sure whether it should be changed somehow, it just looks strange to me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll make some changes. I'm a little confused on your point 2 however and was hoping you could provide a better explanation or an example of what you mean.

Comment: @Scott - regarding second point. Take a look at this `TabControlRegionAdapter` implementation: https://compositewpf.svn.codeplex.com/svn/V2/trunk/CAL/Silverlight/Composite.Presentation/Regions/TabControlRegionAdapter.cs and especially `PrepareContainerForItem` method. It doesn't force views to be of type `TabItem`, istead it wraps them if they are not. This is correct behavior for `Region` IMO. But you instead forcing all you views to be inheritors of `RibbonTab`. It *may* make sense but I'm not sure it does in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to build the tabs first then assign the tabs to the Content property of the hosting control.  That should prevent the overlapping which I believe is caused by you making two requestnavigate calls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this party, but I'm unclear on why a custom region adapter is even required. Why can't you just use the built-in ones? To my mind all the areas in the ribbon one might want to expose already have appropriate adapters.

- `RibbonRegion` => `SelectorRegionAdapter` (each item would be a `RibbonTab`)
- `RibbonTabRegion` => `ItemsControlRegionAdapter` (each item typically a `RibbonGroup`)
- `RibbonApplicationMenuRegion` => `ItemsControlRegionAdapter` (each item typically a `RibbonApplicationMenuItem`)
- `RibbonApplicationMenuAuxiliaryPanelRegion` => `ContentControlRegionAdapter`
- etcetera

I can imagine extending the built-in regions to apply custom sorting logic or the like, but your adapter does not do this.

Answer (score 1):

The Custom `RibbonRegionAdapter` is good. I used this one. But the problem I am facing is as follows.
say, 1 of my module need to show multiple ribbon tabs(`Tab1` & `Tab2`) in the same `ribbon_region` when it is got loaded, not the only `CarTab`.

For that I have written this code:

```
var tab1= new Uri("Tab1", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("RibbonRegion", tab1);

var tab2= new Uri("Tab2", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("RibbonRegion", tab2);
```

Now the issue is, the `Tab1` is getting overlaped by `Tab2` and only the `Tab2` is showing.

Answer (score 0):

One note for anyone else researching this issue: The modules in this application need to be WPF User Control Library projects. Simply replace the XAML in the empty UserControl objects with @Scott's Ribbon Tab XAML shown above. There is no need to wrap the `RibbonTab` object in a `UserControl`.

In this specific case, I don't share @Snowbear's concern about deriving the Ribbon Tab 'view' from a `RibbonTab` control. I agree with his point in a more general situation, but the Ribbon Tab that we are inserting into the Ribbon isn't really a view, per se. In other words, it's not a composite of several different UI controls meant to present a UI or a part of a UI to a user. The Ribbon Tab is a lot more specific than that--it is literally a `RibbonTab` object--a single control--and it can be nothing else.